# Python library, what does "q" stand for in heapq?

Tags: python, heap, heapq

Python has this library heapq, which we can use to perform heap operations.
What does "q" stand for?

Comment: say it out loud: "heap queue"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It literally means what it sounds like: heap queue. The [doco](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) confirms this:

> 8.4. `heapq` — ***Heap queue*** algorithm

Answer (score 0):

So, **Heap queue (or heapq) means the same**. It is basically written in an easy way 'heapq' can we written as 'heap queue'. 
For your better understanding q = 'queue'.
This library provides an implementation of the heap queue algorithm, also known as the priority queue algorithm.